# How to get table data between two time using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, qsqlquery

i am using this below sql query to get the table data those was updating yesterday between 12:00 AM to 11:59 AM. In this query i need to put date on daily basis but i don't want to put date again and again so i want another query to get table data without updating date.

```
select * 
from transaction_persistence
where currentdatetimestamp between '18-MAY-2017 12.00.00 AM' and '18-MAY-2017 11.59.59 AM';
```

Comment: Based on the comment on my answer, the OP is using Oracle and not MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff    yes i am using sql developer for above query

Answer (score 1):

Use `now()` or `curdate()`:

```
select * 
from transaction_persistence
where currentdatetimestamp >= CURDATE() and
      currentdatetimestamp < CURDATE() + interval 12 hour;
```

Note:  When working with date or date/time values, `BETWEEN` is dangerous.  In your case, you are missing one second of every half day.

EDIT:

You get Oracle errors with Oracle, not MySQL:

```
select * 
from transaction_persistence
where currentdatetimestamp >= trunc(sysdate) and
      currentdatetimestamp < trunc(sysdate) + 0.5
```

Comment: in your case it is showing error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 51

Comment: My currentdatetimestamp has a data in this format  '10-APR-2016 10:40:20 AM'

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_SUB()` and  `CURDATE()`

```
 SELECT * 
FROM transaction_persistence
WHERE currentdatetimestamp<CURDATE() AND currentdatetimestamp>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: it is showing  "missing right parenthesis" error in 3 line

Comment: @amanshivhare Can you tell me which server are you using? and also mention mysql client.

Comment: My currentdatetimestamp has a data in this format '10-APR-2016 10:40:20 AM'